# ASP.NET - Localization using SQL database with good performance

Tags: asp.net, database, performance, caching, localization

As part of the ASP.NET website I maintain localization/text translations are handled using text stored in a SQL database and not using ResX files; why it is done this way is down to legacy but that is what we do but it does allow us to make changes fairly easily. Text is stored in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Text](
    [TextID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LanguageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
CONSTRAINT [PK_Text] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TextID] ASC,
    [LanguageID] ASC
)
```

And the code-behind in the website will reference the text IDs for a chosen language to assign the correct text to the HTML elements such as labels etc.

Now because we have so much text available and hitting the database on each page request just to translate a page is so slow what we actually do is cache all the text in that table into server memory at application startup using the [HttpApplicationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178594%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The problem we now have is that, because we have several web servers being load balanced, updating that static cache is becoming difficult; we now have to wait for the app pool to recycle before any changes made become visible. Also as the link above suggests:

> ...storing large blocks of data in application state can fill up server memory, causing the server to page memory to disk.

So what I would like to know is what other solution could I use? I need to be able to cache all this text for higher performance but also be able to update it more regularly than once a day, plus be able to manage this cache across multiple servers.

Comment: Are you using the standard ASP.NET Resource provider model?

Comment: @JohnSaunders no, all text is manually retrieved using unique IDs and manually set to text elements such as labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "distributed cache".  If you Google for that, you'll find some options that should help you.  Some advantages to a distributed cache:

1. Data is stored in RAM, not disk.
2. Data is distributed across many nodes and allows you to scale horizontally (just add a node).
3. The cache will run on their own dedicated machines. This will alleviate the load on your web servers.

Some technologies to look into:

1. AppFabric (works well with .NET): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppFabric#AppFabric_Caching
2. Memcached: http://memcached.org/
3. Couchbase: http://www.couchbase.com/

I've used AppFabric with .NET before and it worked very well for our company. It was easy to add nodes and grow as needed.

Comment: Thank you, definitely something I'll consider as this makes a lot of sense